# Summand in Cauchy product

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following question arose from general observations for particular cases of $a$ and $b$ when working with infinite MA models.

Let $0 < a, b < 1$. Then the Cauchy product formula yields
$$
\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \right)
\left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty b^j \right)=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^k a^i b^{k-i}
$$

Mathematica suggests 
$$  \sum_{i=0}^k a^i b^{k-i} = \frac{a^{k+1} - b^{k+1}}{a - b}, $$
but I have no idea how to prove the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove $\sum_{i=0}^k a^i b^{k-i} = \frac{a^{k+1} - b^{k+1}}{a - b}$ by induction !